# how to get lat and long of device by using cellid in j2me?

Tags: java-me

I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude by using cellid in j2me for non gps nokia mobile.

Comment: java, php, asp.net? smell like `plz-send-me-teh-code` question

Comment: Once Try this link http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Determining_Current_Location_via_Cell_ID Its working in Nokia Asha(210) I already tested this link. This provides output as you specified based on cellid itself. check it once.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible to get hold of Cell ID but you can try using the methods detailed [here](http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=zh-hant/node/3589).  Then try feeding the results into [Open Cell ID](http://www.opencellid.org/) to get the location.